# Asp.net web application in call other asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dll

I have one asp .net web application and i want to build piece by piece my project. I need to use some part my project dll using other web application. How can it ? Because I will use for licensing processing.For example basic one solitions and two asp.net web applications project I want to call asp.net project using method etc. Other asp.net web applications.

Comment: What part of your project you want to use exactly? Only code?

Comment: Many asp.net web application web applications in the same place but I want to disable one web application for licensing.

Comment: What do you mean by licensing? Usually you would just create a common library that both websites use. Or you would simple perform some sort of HTTP operation (webservice or HTTP POST/GET/PUT etc).

Comment: @smtprld - you want disable one application and still use its code?

Comment: @Kamo yes , i want to for example  master application control other application disable or enable .

Comment: @Goku i dont use http post get etc. because my custom using my web application local not internet etc.